# Want to run JavaScript code snippet which returns Boolean with the help of java

Tags: javascript, java, groovy, jjs

I want to run a JavaScript code snippet which returns boolean, from java.

Currently I am using `ProcessBuilder` to run the JavaScript program with the command `jjs filename`.

I am able to perform the operations and getting the output from `getOutputStream` properly.

But my requirement is to return boolean from the script, when I make the similar changes in the script it gives compile time error invalid return statement, which is obvious.

when I use

```
var a=5; var b=6; print(a+b);
```

I am getting a output 11.
But I want to execute a script like

```
var a=5; 
if(a>0) 
    return true; 
else 
    return false;
```

I get errorStream like
Invalid return statement
Expected eof but found }
}
^

Comment: In order to get help, you need to provide some code that shows what you have tried.

Comment: Is the boolean part of the standard output from the js script? Or is it some success/failure state that's given in some other way? If yes, how is it given?

Comment: when I use 
var a=5; var b=6; print(a+b);
I am getting a output 11. 
But I want to execute a script like 
var a=5; 
if(a>0) 
 return true; 
else 
 return false;
I get errorStream like 
Invalid return statement 
Expected eof but found }
}
^

Comment: Hello Federico, I'm not quite understanding your question. I've updated the description with an example please have a look at it.

Comment: Please show exactly what you have, in a way we can run.  We need to see the ProcessBuilder, the full js file, the expected output and the actual output. Plus full errors when they happen

Answer (score 0):

The [getInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream()) method of the [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class gives you a stream from which you can read bytes. You have to convert the bytes to String and then parse to boolean.

Comment: I am getting a compile time error when do the changes in the code for returning boolean. As I am not creating any method to write the code in it. Please mention if I have to use any other way to solve this issue.